# help with a shading issue

Tags: rendering, objects, shaders

I have a model with rocks surrounding it

[image]

In layout i see everything just fine but as soon as i go into shading mode the rocks turn into what looks like mist. Any ideas on what this is and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: Did you accidentally plug the material for your rocks in to the _volume_ of the material output instead of the _surface_?